How to Fix mySQL Database Error In WordPress
After making some changes to a WordPress installation, I started getting the error below. I spent much time checking and fixing the database, dropping and emptying... But the error below remains. Any suggestions?
WordPress database error: [Duplicate column name 'items_in_package']
ALTER TABLE wp_app_stages ADD 'items_in_package' INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AFTER 'forever_active_time'

WordPress database error: [Duplicate column name 'change_stage_id']
ALTER TABLE wp_app_stages ADD 'change_stage_id' INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER 'forever_active_time'

Thanks!

It seems like those columns already exist in the table. As far as I know, wp_app_stages is not part of the standard WordPress database, so it must be part of a plugin, or else something custom in your site.

@BillKarwin you're correct. The error seems to indicate that the table "items_in_package" exists. So, I tried to drop that table thinking that could solve the issue, but it didn't. And yes, "wp_app_stages" is part of a custom post type database table. But I think the first issue or error might be the one triggering the second error.
